# How to re-gridding xarray from higher to lower resolution using IDW

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-requests, python-xarray

I am using winpython 3.6. I have an xarray data for a given region as given below:

```
sea_clt=clt.sel(lat=slice(-13, 31), lon=slice(89,152))
clt_sea_array=sea_clt[:,:,:]

Out[20]: 
<xarray.DataArray 'clt' (time: 20075, lat: 23, lon: 25)>
[11543125 values with dtype=float32]
Coordinates:
  * lat      (lat) float64 -13.0 -11.0 -9.0 -7.0 -5.0 -3.0 -1.0 1.0 3.0 5.0 ...
  * lon      (lon) float64 91.25 93.75 96.25 98.75 101.2 103.8 106.2 108.8 ...
  * time     (time) datetime64[ns] 1950-01-01T12:00:00 1950-01-02T12:00:00 ...
```

The grid spacing is 200km*200km (2.0degree*2.0 degree scale) with daily time series variable. Now I want to re-gridding this data at (50km*50km or 0.5degree*0.5degree grid scale) for each time steps. I tried with reshaping options but not succeeded. I am not able to get any solution of it. How can do this with any standard method like Nearest-Neighbor or IDW? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The nearest-neighbor lookup for data staying on a grid can be done with `reindex`,

```
sea_clt.reindex(lat=lat_new, lon=lot_new, method='nearest')
```

Other interpolations, such as linear interpolation, are not yet implemented in xarray.

For the linear interpolation, the best we can do now might be

```
from scipy.interpolation import interp1d

def interp(y_src, x_src, x_dest, **kwargs):
    return interp1d(x_src, y_src, **kwargs)(x_dest)

new_da = sea_clt
new_da = xr.apply_ufunc(interp, new_da, input_core_dims=[['lat']], 
                        output_core_dims=[['lat_new']], 
                        kwargs={'x_src': new_da['lat'], 'x_dest': lat_new})
new_da.coords['lat_new'] = lat_new

new_da = xr.apply_ufunc(interp, new_da, input_core_dims=[['lon']], 
                        output_core_dims=[['lon_new']], 
                        kwargs={'x_src': new_da['lon'], 'x_dest': lon_new})
new_da.coords['lon_new'] = lon_new
```

Comment: Since `xarray v0.10.8` one can now use your (@Keisuke FUJII) function `interp_like` for this purpose, if I'm not mistaken?

Comment: @climatestudent Yes, now xarray has `interp` and `interp_like`, which I have implemented ;) Use these methods instead.

Answer (score 2):

You can also try the [xEMSF package](http://xesmf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/why.html), it seems to provide powerful methods to regrid xarray data.

Comment: but it has no options to work on windows using spyder

Comment: Spyder is an IDE (interactive development environment), xEMSF is a python package, so  are 2 different things!

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to regrid from lower resolution to higher resolution on spatial scale. One way is to use interp_like method of xarray. The following is a sample code.

```
import xarray as xr
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
ds1=xr.open_dataset("etopo40.cdf")
ds2=xr.open_dataset("etopo20.cdf")
ds1=ds1.rename({'ETOPO40Y': 'lat', 'ETOPO40X':'lon'})
ds2=ds2.rename({'ETOPO20Y': 'lat', 'ETOPO20X1_1081':'lon'})
# print(ds1)
# print(ds2)
rose40=ds1.ROSE
rose20=ds2.ROSE
rose_interp=rose40.interp_like(rose20)
```

Answer (score 0):

while applying your code, getting this error:

```
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
lat_new = np.linspace(0.5, -13, 31)
lon_new = np.linspace(0.5, 89,152)


def interp(y_src, x_src, x_dest, **kwargs):
    return interp1d(x_src, y_src, **kwargs)(x_dest)


new_da = sea_clt
new_da = xarray.apply_ufunc(interp, new_da, input_core_dims=[['lat']], 
                        output_core_dims=[['lat_new']], 
                        kwargs={'x_src': new_da['lat'], 'x_dest': lat_new})
new_da.coords['lat_new'] = lat_new

new_da = xarray.apply_ufunc(interp, new_da, input_core_dims=[['lon']], 
                        output_core_dims=[['lon_new']], 
                        kwargs={'x_src': new_da['lon'], 'x_dest': lon_new})
new_da.coords['lon_new'] = lon_new
```

Not getting where I am doing mistake. The error is here:

```
  File "C:\python3\WinPython\python-3.6.5.amd64\lib\site-packages\scipy\interpolate\interpolate.py", line 663, in _check_bounds
    raise ValueError("A value in x_new is below the interpolation "

ValueError: A value in x_new is below the interpolation range.
```

Comment: By default, scipy.interpolate.interp1d raises an Error if you try to extrapolate.
To avoid this, add an additional kwargs, `fill_value : “extrapolate”`.

See https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp1d.html
for the detail.

Comment: I solved it but problem is that my region is too large so when i am regridding it at 50km scale from 200km scale so python is taking too much time and while i m saving this data into csv so the file size is too much in GBs. How to make process fast and how can i do compression while saving data

Comment: @VishalSingh. Use netcdf; outputting large datasets to csv is rarely a good idea.